# C# Visual Studio Share a View Across Projects in a Solution says the Shared class does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, symlink

[image]

I have a Solution that looks like the image above. I created a Project called Precheck that is a MainWindow with a PreCheckView.xaml.

I created a second project called Agent Manager. Agent Manager will have 3 views and one of them will be the PreCheckView. I added the PreCheckView.xaml into my Agent Manager Project as a link. Now in the Agent Manager Project I am getting The name 'initializeComponent' does not exist in the current context and it's referring to PreCheckView.xaml. How can I get this View to work in both Projects? I assume it's some sort of namespacing error?

Edit: [image]
I'm also getting this error when I hover over InitializeComponent.

Comment: Sounds like it's looking for the code-behind file PreCheckView.xaml.cs: in the constructor of the code behind the first thing that's being called is InitializeComponent()

Comment: See edit: I see In my Precheck project the File is PreCheckView.xaml and underneath it is the PrecheckView.xaml.cs But in Agent Manager it is only the PreCheckView.xaml.cs. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: False alarm! When I went to add the file, my file browsers File Types did not include all files so .xaml were excluded, but .xaml.cs were included. This fixed it.